# Javascript regex to find PHP object

Tags: php, javascript, regex, object

How can i find a php objects property using regex in javascript?

For example, heres some php.

```
 $obj = new stdClass();
 $obj->name = '';
```

With the regex, i wish to get `name`.

I imagine the regex would look for a `/\$\w+/` variable followed by `->`, or maybe only `->`?

The purpose for the regex is to extend some syntax highlighting.

Comment: Are you trying to parse PHP code with Javascript?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not at all! Im just extending some syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

`\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*->\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*([^;]+);` will work assuming no quoted semicolons; if you have quoted semicolons, regexes are a bad choice. First group is the variable name and the second is the assignment.

Comment: For some reason im having trouble with the `->` part. If i shorten the code to test what breaks, `\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*-` will select `$obj-`, but '\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*->' will not select `$obj->`... Any reason why that could be?

Comment: Interesting, i figured out the reason why i have been having trouble with this is because at some point the code is going back and forth between html entities. So `$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*-&gt;` actually works for me.